# I'm getting Operation not permitted error while starting the mysql service in my docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As the title says, I've this docker compose file:

```
version: '4'

services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
  nginx:
    container_name: myapp_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - app
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: myapp_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    user: mysql 
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "myapp_db"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "myrootpass"

networks:
  default:
    name: app-network
    driver: bridge
```

the app and nginx service starts fine but the db service (mysql) is throwing this error.

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool': Operation not permitted
```

**What is the reason and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` docker image runs under the `root` user, however when the `mysqld` server is started, it drops its privileges and uses the `mysql` user.

In the attached configuration, the folder `./data/mysql` on the host is mounted in `/var/lib/mysql` in the container. The MySQL server tries to change the ownership of the data files to be `mysql`, but does likely not have the rights to do so on the host.

A way to fix this is to change the ownership of the `./data/mysql` folder to the `mysql` user from the host directly.

**You should be able to do so using: `sudo chown -R 999:999 ./data/mysql` on the host.**

Note: I mapped the `mysql` user to its user id using the command `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh mysql:8 -c "getent passwd"`, in case the `mysql` user had another id on the host if it ever existed.